# Deleting an entry from list and inserting into another one. Android

Tags: android, listview

If there are two lists in a same view, how can I move entry in one list to other on a click. I made the listviews and made the adapters for both of them. One list is pending connection and other is approved connections. each entry in pending connections has an accept and a reject button. On rejecting the entry should be deleted. I could do that part. I kept a override function in adapter of pending list connection for reject button. Now on accept I have to insert that same entry into accepted list. I am not able to do it because the adapters of both the listviews are different and I dont know how to access them from the activity.java file. Can some one please help me? 
Thanks in advance.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Pendingheading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pending Connections"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dip" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/pendingconnectionslist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dip" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/approvedheading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Approved Connections"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:padding="10dip"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/approvedconnectionslist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dip" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep reference of `Adapter`s in your activity like:

```
private ListAdapter mFirstAdapter;
private ListAdapter mSecondAdapter;
```

Now in your `ListAdapter` add a method to add or remove item from the list. Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding or removing data.

Now you can listen to click event on `ListAdapter` using  `OnClickListener()` method. Inside this listener you can call the method you created.

Good luck!